# Nomear colunas geradas pelo Summarise() e utilizar divisão na mesma função

Tags: r, dplyr

`df` é o data frame com os dados que irei trabalhar

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 30, ncol = 6))
colnames(df) <- c("ano","mes","x1","x2","x3","x4")

df$ano <- c(2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004)
df$mes <- c(5,9,7,3,8,2,4,1,6,10,2,11,12,10,12,2,8,9,10,7,6,4,5,7,3,1,9,5,2,6)
df$x1 <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60)
df$x2 <- c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90)
df$x3 <- c(4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64,68,72,76,80,84,88,92,96,100,104,108,112,116,120)
df$x4 <- c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,105,110,115,120,125,130,135,140,145,150)

View(df)
```

`resumo` é o data frame onde quero que minhas análises sejam registradas de forma a exportar em .csv ao final

```
resumo <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 12, ncol = 7))
colnames(resumo) <- c("mes","media_diaria_X1","media_mensal_X1","media_diaria_X4","media_mensal_X4","media_diaria_x3_divido_x4","media_mensal_x3_divido_x4")
resumo$mes <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

View(resumo)

library(dplyr)
```

Quando eu utilizo o pacote dplyr ele me retorna valores com as colunas nomeadas iguais as colunas do data frame `df` visto que a seleção é realizada pelas colunas de `df`.
A grande questão é que gostaria que os resultados obtidos abaixo fossem registrados no data frame `resumo` com as colunas nomeadas de acordo com o que defini acima .

Abaixo são os cálculos que consegui fazer e que pretendo fazer com o auxílio de alguém:

Calculo das medias diarias de x1 e x4

```
media_diaria <- df %>%
  group_by(mes) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(x1,x4), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

dput(media_diaria)
structure(list(mes = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    x1 = c(34, 31, 29, 29, 34.6666666666667, 40, 31.3333333333333, 
    22, 31.3333333333333, 28.6666666666667, 24, 28), x4 = c(85, 
    77.5, 72.5, 72.5, 86.6666666666667, 100, 78.3333333333333, 
    55, 78.3333333333333, 71.6666666666667, 60, 70)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Calculo das medias mensais (referente a soma mensal) de x1 e x4

```
soma_mensal <- df %>% 
  group_by(ano,mes) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(x1,x4), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
media_mensal <- soma_mensal %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(x1,x4), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

dput(soma_mensal)
structure(list(ano = c(2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004), mes = c(2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 12, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), x1 = c(22, 
44, 48, 42, 6, 4, 24, 26, 52, 44, 58, 48, 10, 28, 30, 16, 58, 
14, 56, 78, 40, 34, 90, 58), x4 = c(55, 110, 120, 105, 15, 10, 
60, 65, 130, 110, 145, 120, 25, 70, 75, 40, 145, 35, 140, 195, 
100, 85, 225, 145)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    ano = c(2002, 2003, 2004), .rows = structure(list(1:8, 9:15, 
        16:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dput(media_mensal)
structure(list(mes = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    x1 = c(34, 41.3333333333333, 58, 29, 52, 60, 31.3333333333333, 
    22, 47, 43, 24, 28), x4 = c(85, 103.333333333333, 145, 72.5, 
    130, 150, 78.3333333333333, 55, 117.5, 107.5, 60, 70)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

A partir desse ponto os cálculos não deram certo e não consigo resolver.

Cálculos da média diária com o resultado obtido da dividão de x3 por x4. Não deu certo!

```
media_diaria_divisao <- df %>%
  group_by(mes) %>%
  summarise_at((df$x3/df$x4), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a double vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Cálculo das medias mensais (referente a soma mensal) de x1 e x4. Também não deu certo!

```
soma_mensal <- df %>% 
  group_by(ano,mes) %>%
  summarise_at((df$x3/df$x4), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
media_mensal <- soma_mensal %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise_at((df$x3/df$x4), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a double vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Resumindo minhas duas dúvidas:

1. Como consigo realizar as 2 análises acima em relação à divisão de x3/x4 com o `dplyr`? Caso utilizar o `dplyr` não seja uma boa opção, qual seria uma solução possível utilizando funções? Estou tentando evitar trabalhar com loops.
2. Como faço para alimentar o dataframe `resumo` com os resultados das análises acima?

Comment: Eu não entendi a diferença entre `media_diaria` e `media_mensal`. Os resultados estão iguais, ao menos no exemplo fornecido.

Comment: Marcus Nunes considerando a coluna X1 por exemplo: para o cálculo da media_diaria foi realizado um agrupamento com todos os dados referentes ao mês de Janeiro por exemplo, que é representado pelo número 1 no dataframe, e em seguida realizei a média. 
Já para a media_mensal primeiramente foi realizada uma soma dos valores de cada mês em relação ao seu ano e depois realizada a média dessa somatória. Janeiro/2002 teve uma somatória, Janeiro/2003 teve outra somatória e assim por diante. Em seguida eu realizei a media dessa somatória e obtive a média_mensal.

Comment: Imagens são difíceis de ver, poste os valores e formate com 4 espaços de margem, por favor. Quanto ao código, não estará à procura de `summarise(med_dia_divisao = mean(x3/x4, na.rm = TRUE))` no primeiro que não deu certo? Nos outros a solução deverá ser semelhante.

Comment: Rui Barradas retirei as imagens e coloquei `dput` de cada um dos data frames. Quanto a sugestão que você me apresentou, não deu certo, até tinha tentado dessa forma antes, mas ele me retorna um único valor para todos os meses (valor=0.8), sendo que deveria ser um valor específico para cada mês. Marcus Nunes, talvez com os `dput` que acrescentei, fique melhor a visualização. Como são poucos valores, em alguns casos media_diaria e media_mensal estão coincidindo, mas se você observar o mês 10 (outubro) já possui diferença entre elas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `mutate´;

```
media_diaria_divisao <- df %>% mutate(x3_x4=x3/x4) %>%
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(x1,x4,x3_x4), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

soma_mensal_div <- df %>% mutate(x3_x4=x3/x4) %>%
  group_by(ano,mes) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(x1,x4,x3_x4), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
media_mensal_div <- soma_mensal_div %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(x1,x4,x3_x4), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

rtemp=merge(media_diaria_divisao,media_mensal_div,by="mes")
resumo[]=rtemp[,c(1,2,5,3,6,4,7)]


#> resumo
#   mes media_diaria_X1 media_mensal_X1 media_diaria_X4 media_mensal_X4 media_diaria_x3_divido_x4 media_mensal_x3_divido_x4
#1    1        34.00000        34.00000        85.00000        85.00000                       0.8                  0.800000
#2    2        31.00000        41.33333        77.50000       103.33333                       0.8                  1.066667
#3    3        29.00000        58.00000        72.50000       145.00000                       0.8                  1.600000
#4    4        29.00000        29.00000        72.50000        72.50000                       0.8                  0.800000
#5    5        34.66667        52.00000        86.66667       130.00000                       0.8                  1.200000
#6    6        40.00000        60.00000       100.00000       150.00000                       0.8                  1.200000
#7    7        31.33333        31.33333        78.33333        78.33333                       0.8                  0.800000
#8    8        22.00000        22.00000        55.00000        55.00000                       0.8                  0.800000
#9    9        31.33333        47.00000        78.33333       117.50000                       0.8                  1.200000
#10  10        28.66667        43.00000        71.66667       107.50000                       0.8                  1.200000
#11  11        24.00000        24.00000        60.00000        60.00000                       0.8                  0.800000
#12  12        28.00000        28.00000        70.00000        70.00000                       0.8                  0.800000
```

Comment: Robert agradeço muito! Deu certo! Somente a media_diaria_x3_divido_x4 que ficou um pouco diferente! Mas creio que seja questão de interpretação mesmo, a parte essencial que foi a utilização das funções em conjunto já me clareou bastante!